# How to get this probability outcome in R?

Tags: r, probability, probability-theory, probability-distribution

New to R. Not sure how to go about this problem. Essentially I want to create a Monte Carlo simulation. However this is how it's supposed to go:
There are only 3 people (A,B,C) And only come into contact once in this order: (A-->B) (B-->C). Starting out, A is 100% sick, while B and C are 0% sick. Each time a person comes into contact with another, they have a 50% chance of being sick How would i go and replicate that in R?  I understand the mathematics behind this but unsure how to code it. This is what i have so far:

```
a='positive'
corona = c('positive','negative')
sample(x = corona, size = 1, replace = TRUE)
```

I know the output will only give me the results of whether B is sick or not. How would i continue to see if C is sick?

Comment: How exactly do you want to simulate these "contacts" between people? How do you decide who starts out as sick or not? How large is your population? How often do the encounters happen? This does not seem like a very straight forward problem. There are lot of other decisions that need to be made for your model. If seems like you might first needs some statistics help before trying to program such a model. Perhaps you could first ask for modeling advice over at [stats.se] where statistics question are on-topic.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the questions; I didn't explain the question very well. There are only 3 people (A,B,C) And only come into contact in once in this order: (A-->B) (B-->C). Starting out, A is 100% sick, while B and C are 0% sick. Each time a person comes into contact with another, they have a 50% chance of being sick.Also would Cross Validated be able to help in R? or is it only the mathematics behind the probability? Because i know the mathematics behind it and what the answer should be, just not sure how to code it in R.

Comment: OK. That further description helps a lot. It would be good to edit that into the original question. How often do you want to repeat this experiment? And the goal is just to see how often C is sick? Cross Validated is more so for the theory (though many do use R to actually do the analysis). Your model here is much more simple that at first I thought so maybe that's not necessary. Though this seems like maybe an odd choice for simulation when there is a pretty clear theoretical solution here. Person C will be sick 25% of the time (1 * .5 * .5)

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the clarification on Cross Validated. And as I said, I understand the simple mathematics behind it, just unsure how to code it in R. I want to simulate it 1000 times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write a helper function to do the "infecting". Let's assume that 1 is "sick" and 0 is "not sick"

```
infect <- function(x, rate=.5) {
   current_sick <- x==1
   new_sick <- runif(sum(current_sick)) < rate
   x[current_sick] <- as.numeric(new_sick) # turn TRUE/FALSE to 1/0
   x
}
```

This function looks where all the 1's are, then for each of those individuals, it tosses a coin to see of the next person will be sick (not changing any of the non-sick values)

Then to test with 1000 people, you can do

```
A <- rep(1, 1000) # all sick
B <- infect(A)
C <- infect(B)
```

This draws 1000 A's. And we go though two transmission steps, doing all 1000 samples at once. If you run `mean(C)` you should get something close to 0.25.

Comment: Thank you. If it's not too much, can you explain what you did? runif, as.numeric, etc. Or if you had any suggestions for what I could read to learn R better, I'd greatly appreciate it!

Comment: `runif()` is how you draw a random number uniformly between 0 and 1. `as.numeric` just turns TRUE/FALSE values to the numbers 1/0. "Learning R better" is far too big a topic to suggest a quick reference for. Writing simulations is a much broader topic than data cleaning or standard statistical analysis.I don't have any good recommendations where to start